# Browser for Java Swing Jinternalframe

Tags: java, swing, browser

I need to integrate a browser in a JInternalFrame. I tried a lot of different ideas:

- [jcef](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef): It is based on heavyweight components an so don't work with swing
- [jxBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser): is only compatible to java 8
- swt Browser: works in a JFrame but not JInternalFrame, Problem is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672818/swt-browser-in-swing-jinternalframe) question

Does someone has another Idea how to integrate a browser to swing? It should be able to show Pages, which shows webGL and compatible with java 9 and 10.

I already saw some similar questions on SO, but those are 10 years and older and don't fit for my purpose

Comment: In reality, you're not going to have any luck, the reason is, Swing uses a single native peer to render the entire UI on, where embedded browser support requires access to the Windows native peer itself (ie `JInternalFrame` does not have a native peer of it's own). I'd recommend looking towards JavaFX instead

Comment: I know that it is difficult, but it already worked with the jxBrowser, so I thought there is a solution for newer JDK versions. I also think that it might be possible with the swt browser and the awt_swt bridge, I'm trying with it

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and it worked with [The DJ Project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/main/index.html). It contains a library, that uses the swt browser and has a API for Java Swing applications.